# php sorting long strings in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, decimal

I have a directory listing that I need to sort. so far natsort works well except when a decimal is introduced.  009 comes after 009.1 I am trying to work on getting all the special char's out of the directory names and havent had issues with them so far.  "http://10.1.1.1/manual/product/v02/secton 3/part 3.1 leveling/002.jpg"  some get as long as 150 or so char's long. Since these are long strings with occasional decimals its not easy to get them properly sorted. I dont believe . are used any where except for decimals and the file extension

Every thing I have read so far ignores decimals.  0200 is before 100 in cases like that I would hope that specials would come after # and letters but appairently not.

Comment: Just updated to PHP 5.3 a little while back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have sorting requirements that can't be met by any existing PHP functions, your best bet is to call [usort()](http://www.php.net/usort) and write your own comparison function.

Sample

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a, $b); # replace with your own comparison logic
}
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: That looks like the best solution built in to php,  I will either end up using that or changing the directory structure.  9.1 vs 9a  putting a letter instead of .1 allows natsort to work as expected.